# Determine 3D touch availability for the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3dtouch

I want to know if the device supports 3D Touch. I don't like to use the [`forceTouchCapability`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1623515-forcetouchcapability) property of the `UITraitCollection`, because it may return `unavailable` for iPhone 6s if the user has turned off 3D Touch in the settings.

**I want to know if 3D Touch is available by hardware, regardless to the settings.** The only possible solution which I see is to check device's model. But, may be, someone can suggest more stable and simple solution.

**Background:** I have added [Home Screen Actions](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/home-screen-actions/) to the app, and I want to notify user about it, only if the device supports them.

Comment: What's the difference between the case when 3d touch is not available for device and when it is turned off by user?

Comment: @Sulthan, the difference is that 3D Touch is turned off, the user can turn it on, which is not possible when the technology is not available for the device.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you *won't* be able to check the exact feature that you are asking for, checking the availability of 3d touch is *not* only related to the device model:

> Keys that indicate the availability of 3D Touch on a device. Only
>   certain devices support 3D Touch. On those that do, **the user can**
>   **disable 3D Touch in the Accessibility area in Settings**.
>
> <sub>[UIForceTouchCapability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiforcetouchcapability)</sub>

Meaning that the system tells your application that the 3d touch is unavailable, regardless whether the device does support 3d touch or not, which explain what you mentioned:

> I don't like to use the `forceTouchCapability` property of the
>   UITraitCollection, because it may return unavailable for iPhone 6s if
>   the user has turned off 3D Touch in settings.

However, you are able to detect changes to 3D Touch availability while your app is running, by implementing [traitCollectionDidChange(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange) as mentioned in [Checking the Availability of 3D Touch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/tracking_the_force_of_3d_touch_events/checking_the_availability_of_3d_touch) article:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    // Update the app's 3D Touch support.
    if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
        // Enable 3D Touch features
    } else {
        // Fall back to other non 3D Touch features.
    }
}
```

Regarding to:

> The only possible solution which I see is to check device model

Personally, I think it doesn't make sense to do such a thing, because -as I mentioned above- it is controlled by the system; At some point, it won't make a difference whether the device not support 3d touch or if the use disabled the 3d touch, it should leads the the same result referring to your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I knew it all.